# Apache reverse proxy to ASP.NET Core application in a docker container

Tags: docker, apache2, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to setup a ASP.NET Core 3.1 web applcation on a Rasberry Pi 4 running CentOS7 for ARM64. The setup seems to be a bit complicated when using ARM64 arch. I want the application to be run inside a docker container since I have issues running dotnet directly and also to push updated images to a self-hosted docker registry.

I'm using apache2 (httpd) as a reverse proxy to the application and the registry. I'm unable to proxy to the docker container running the web application through localhost port mapping which I'm able to do with the registry container. Furthermore, I can access the container with through 192.168.0.11:8080 which makes this even more weird.

When I try to proxy th ASP.NET Core through localhost application, it seems that the redirection fails and returns "503 Service Unavailable". The VirtualHost for the applcation is listed below

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    ServerName example.com
    ProxyPreservehost On
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
    #cert stuff removed
</VirtualHost>
```

and the command I use to start the container is as follows

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 registry.example.com/aspnetcore_app:latest
```

I can succesfully proxy to the container IP address however this approach seems to complicate the SSL encryption setup from apache. Although I'm not 100% sure about this. What is really confusing is that, atleast from my understadning, I should be able to acces the container through localhost:8080 when the docker container is started with `-p 8080:80` as the port mapping works just fine for my self-hosted registry.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be faily common as I found multiple posts with the same command to fix the issue. By running the following command

```
/usr/sbin/setsebool httpd_can_network_connect 1
```

I'm able to proxy to http://localhost:8080 as I couldn't before. What I find fairly confusing is how I was able to proxy to http://localhost:8443 before I ran the command but only localhost:8080 after the command...